# Webpack bundle served to Firebase hosting incomplete, no issue using Webpack server

Tags: javascript, firebase, webpack, bundle, firebase-hosting

All JS code is bundled with Webpack into a main.js file. Images, style.css and index.html are handled using miniCSSExtractPlugin, asset/resource and HTMLWebpackPlugin. The index.js file is imported into index.html by HTMLWebpackPlugin when the bundle is generated.

Webpack config looks like :

```
    const config = {
     entry: "./src/index.js",
     mode: 'none',
     experiments: {
       futureDefaults: true,
     },
     output: {
       path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
       filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
       clean: true,
     },
     devServer: {
       open: true,
       host: "localhost",
       static: {
         directory: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
       },
     },
     module: {
       rules: [
         {
           test: /\.js$/,
           use: 'babel-loader',
           exclude: /node_modules/
         },
         {
           test: /\.css$/,
           sideEffects: true,
            include: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/style.css'),
           ],
           use: [
             MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
             'css-loader'
           ]
         },
         {
          test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
          type: 'asset/resource'
         },
       ],
     },
     plugins: [
       new MiniCssExtractPlugin(
         { filename: '[name].[contenthash].css' },
         { experimentalUseImportModule: false },
       ),
       new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
         title: 'go outside today',
         template: './src/indexTemplate.html'
       }),
     ],
   };
```

When this is served using webpack-dev-server, everything displays correctly, save for this error:

```
ERROR in webpack/runtime/css loading
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getChunkConditionMap'
```

)

However, it doesn't affect content being served.

When code is bundled and served to Firebase emulators or Firebase hosting, all the code in index.js such as a simple console.log() disappears. However, all the functions imported into index.js that are meant to exectute and display on the site work. There is no issue with the style.css, index.html, or anything else in the main.js bundle.

The following issue is displayed:

```
caught (in promise) TypeError: c[e] is not a function
```

Looking through the main.js bundled file when served to Firebase, this is where the error is:

```
function l(e) {
    var t = u[e];
    if (void 0 !== t)
        return t.exports;
    var r = u[e] = {
        exports: {}
    };
    return c[e](r, r.exports, l),
    r.exports
}
```

Not sure what the issue might be. Looking through the bundle, there's no issue with the index.js import into the index.html file. The rest of main.js works correctly. Only thing not displaying are the function code in index.js. All imports work normally from index.js including style.css, other functions, etc.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you build locally and serve the static files using something like [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve)

Comment: I do. I did some debugging - the error is in the importing of the styles.css using Webpack's MiniCssExtractPlugin which blocks the rest of index.js. But still stuck.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76278000/error-when-hosting-css-bundle-with-firebase-minicssextractplugin-webpack