# Error when hosting CSS bundle with Firebase - MiniCSSExtractPlugin Webpack

Tags: javascript, firebase, webpack, firebase-hosting

I previously posted a question [Webpack bundle served to Firebase hosting incomplete, no issue using Webpack server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76277302/webpack-bundle-served-to-firebase-hosting-incomplete-no-issue-using-webpack-ser)  regarding an error when serving a Webpack bundle to Firebase, where the index.js code does not execute and throws an error like

```
caught (in promise) TypeError: c[e] is not a function
```

The issue was resolved when I removed the import of './style.css': which is loaded by the miniCSSExtractPlugin to output a CSS bundle into the public folder.

It seems that there is an issue with this import -> such that the rest of index.js does not execute when it is served with Firebase. However, I can't remove the import as it's necessary for Webpack to bundle it into the public folder. Could this be an issue with the config of MiniCSSExtractPlugin when served publicly?

My config file looks like

```
plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(
      { filename: '[name].[contenthash].css' },
    ),
```

There are no issues with any of the other types of bundled files such as images and html.